# Generate new dataframe from another dataframe with some conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have extracted logs and converted into df into below format

|  | date | level | message | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2023-03-23 13:29:04 | INFO | arguments passed: | asd |
| 1 | 2023-03-23 13:29:05 | INFO | waiting to get data |  |
| 2 | 2023-03-23 13:29:12 | INFO | waiting to get data |  |
| 3 | 2023-03-23 13:29:12 | INFO | time started: | 2023-03-23 13:29:12.016772 |
| 4 | 2023-03-23 13:29:12 | INFO | start time for bulk : | 2023-03-23 13:29:12.017505 |
| 5 | 2023-03-23 13:29:12 | INFO | time taken for process data to complete: | 0 days 00:00:00.000105 |
| 6 | 2023-03-23 13:29:12 | INFO | data to ingest: | 1 |
| 7 | 2023-03-23 13:29:17 | INFO | Load target table completed with Append | 0 days 00:00:04.991501 |
| 8 | 2023-03-23 13:29:17 | INFO | Published messages with custom attributes to | oiolk |
| 9 | 2023-03-23 13:29:18 | INFO | time taken | 0 days 00:00:06.243332 |
| 10 | 2023-03-23 13:29:18 | INFO | waiting to get data |  |
| 11 | 2023-03-23 13:29:18 | INFO | time started: | 2023-03-23 13:29:18.261479 |
| 12 | 2023-03-23 13:29:18 | INFO | start time for bulk : | 2023-03-23 13:29:18.262466 |
| 13 | 2023-03-23 13:29:18 | INFO | time taken for process data to complete: | 0 days 00:00:00.000113 |
| 14 | 2023-03-23 13:29:18 | INFO | data to ingest: | 1 |
| 15 | 2023-03-23 13:29:22 | INFO | Load target table completed with Append | 0 days 00:00:03.970353 |
| 16 | 2023-03-23 13:29:22 | INFO | Published messages with custom attributes to | oio |
| 17 | 2023-03-23 13:29:23 | INFO | time taken | 0 days 00:00:05.006077 |
| 18 | 2023-03-23 13:29:23 | INFO | waiting to get data |  |
| 19 | 2023-03-23 13:29:23 | INFO | time started: | 2023-03-23 13:29:23.269162 |
| 20 | 2023-03-23 13:29:23 | INFO | start time for bulk : | 2023-03-23 13:29:23.270157 |
| 21 | 2023-03-23 13:29:23 | INFO | time taken for process data to complete: | 0 days 00:00:00.000089 |
| 22 | 2023-03-23 13:29:23 | INFO | data to ingest: | 1 |
| 23 | 2023-03-23 13:29:27 | INFO | Load target table completed with Append | 0 days 00:00:04.059465 |
| 24 | 2023-03-23 13:29:27 | INFO | Published messages with custom attributes to | jnhj |
| 25 | 2023-03-23 13:29:28 | INFO | time taken | 0 days 00:00:05.194268 |
| 26 | 2023-03-23 13:29:28 | INFO | waiting to get data |  |
| 27 | 2023-03-23 13:29:28 | INFO | time started: | 2023-03-23 13:29:28.464997 |
| 28 | 2023-03-23 13:29:28 | INFO | start time for bulk : | 2023-03-23 13:29:28.466010 |
| 29 | 2023-03-23 13:29:28 | INFO | time taken for process data to complete: | 0 days 00:00:00.000086 |
| 30 | 2023-03-23 13:29:28 | INFO | data to ingest: | 1 |
| 31 | 2023-03-23 13:29:35 | ERROR | Error 500 | service not available |
| 33 | 2023-03-23 13:29:36 | INFO | time taken | 0 days 00:00:07.549076 |
| 34 | 2023-04-17 07:47:51 | INFO | waiting to get data |  |
| 35 | 2023-04-17 07:47:55 | ERROR | cosumer error | unable to consume messages |
| 36 | 2023-04-17 07:47:51 | INFO | waiting to get data |  |

I need to consider a row from "time started:" to "time taken" and no errors in between then type will be INFO else the type will be ERROR(update error msg column as well). If any error after "time taken" to "time started" then all columns will be N/A and error msg to be logged as one row

new df from above df as below

| date | type | data to ingest | time started | time taken for process data | Append Time | time taken | Error message | updated time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-03-23 13:29:12 | info | 1 | 2023-03-23 13:29:12.016772 | 0 days 00:00:00.000105 | 0 days 00:00:04.991501 | 0 days 00:00:06.243332 | N/A | currenttime stamp |
| 2023-03-23 13:29:18 | info | 1 | 2023-03-23 13:29:18.261479 | :0 days 00:00:00.000113 | :0 days 00:00:03.970353 | 0 days 00:00:05.006077 | N/A | current time stamp |
| 2023-03-23 13:29:23 | info | 1 | 2023-03-23 13:29:23.269162 | :0 days 00:00:00.000089 | : 0 days 00:00:04.059465 | 0 days 00:00:05.194268 | N/A | current time stamp |
| 2023-03-23 13:29:28 | ERROR | 1 | 2023-03-23 13:29:28.464997 | :0 days 00:00:00.000086 | : N/A | N/A | Error 500 service not available | current time stamp |
| 2023-04-17 07:47:55 | ERROR | N/A | N/A | :N/A | : N/A | N/A | cosumer error unable to consume messages | current time stamp |

how to generate new df as mentioned above with the checks mentioned in python

i tried below code but not working throwing error type errors e.t.c

based on answer suggestion i tried below code, still not achieved

```
df['date_clean'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y-%m-%d %X')
df = df.sort_values('date', ascending=True)


start_rows = df[df['message'] == 'time started:']
end_rows = df[df['message'] == 'time taken']


df_to_return = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)


processed_rows = []
for index, row in start_rows.iterrows():
    next_end_row_index = end_rows.loc[row['date'] < end_rows['date']].index[0]


    df_subset = df.loc[index:next_end_row_index]
    
    error = False
    error_msg = ""
    print(df_subset)
    for index, subset_row in df_subset.iterrows():
        print(subset_row)
        if subset_row.level == "ERROR":
            error = True
            error_msg = subset_row.message
        else:
            message_parts = subset_row.message
            print(message_parts)
            data_to_ingest = message_parts[1].strip()
            time_started = message_parts[2].strip()
            time_taken = message_parts[3].strip()
            append_time = message_parts[4].strip()
            time_taken_for_process_data = subset_row['time taken']


       
        if error:
                processed_rows.append({
                    'date': None,
                    'type': 'ERROR',
                    'data to ingest': None,
                    'time started': None,
                    'time taken for process data': None,
                    'Append Time': None,
                    'time taken': None,
                    'Error message': error_msg,
                    'updated time': None
                })
                error = False
                error_msg = ""
        else:
            processed_rows.append({
                'date': subset_row.date_clean,
                'type': 'INFO',
                'data to ingest': data_to_ingest,
                'time started': time_started,
                'time taken for process data': time_taken_for_process_data,
                'Append Time': append_time,
                'time taken': time_taken,
                'Error message': None,
                'updated time': None
            })


    df_to_return = pd.DataFrame(processed_rows)
```

Please suggest me where am doing wrong or efficient way to achieve my goal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rearrange the labels and error messages a bit, remove the 'waiting to get data' rows and other unnecessary messages, then pivot the dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
import io
data = 'date,level,message,value\r\n2023-03-23 13:29:04,INFO,arguments passed:,asd\r\n2023-03-23 13:29:05,INFO,waiting to get data,\r\n2023-03-23 13:29:12,INFO,waiting to get data,\r\n2023-03-23 13:29:12,INFO,time started:,2023-03-23 13:29:12.016772\r\n2023-03-23 13:29:12,INFO,start time for bulk :,2023-03-23 13:29:12.017505\r\n2023-03-23 13:29:12,INFO,time taken for process data to complete:,0 days 00:00:00.000105\r\n2023-03-23 13:29:12,INFO,data to ingest:,1\r\n2023-03-23 13:29:17,INFO,Load target table completed with Append,0 days 00:00:04.991501\r\n2023-03-23 13:29:17,INFO,Published messages with custom attributes to,oiolk\r\n2023-03-23 13:29:18,INFO,time taken,0 days 00:00:06.243332\r\n2023-03-23 13:29:18,INFO,waiting to get data,\r\n2023-03-23 13:29:18,INFO,time started:,2023-03-23 13:29:18.261479\r\n2023-03-23 13:29:18,INFO,start time for bulk :,2023-03-23 13:29:18.262466\r\n2023-03-23 13:29:18,INFO,time taken for process data to complete:,0 days 00:00:00.000113\r\n2023-03-23 13:29:18,INFO,data to ingest:,1\r\n2023-03-23 13:29:22,INFO,Load target table completed with Append,0 days 00:00:03.970353\r\n2023-03-23 13:29:22,INFO,Published messages with custom attributes to,oio\r\n2023-03-23 13:29:23,INFO,time taken,0 days 00:00:05.006077\r\n2023-03-23 13:29:23,INFO,waiting to get data,\r\n2023-03-23 13:29:23,INFO,time started:,2023-03-23 13:29:23.269162\r\n2023-03-23 13:29:23,INFO,start time for bulk :,2023-03-23 13:29:23.270157\r\n2023-03-23 13:29:23,INFO,time taken for process data to complete:,0 days 00:00:00.000089\r\n2023-03-23 13:29:23,INFO,data to ingest:,1\r\n2023-03-23 13:29:27,INFO,Load target table completed with Append,0 days 00:00:04.059465\r\n2023-03-23 13:29:27,INFO,Published messages with custom attributes to,jnhj\r\n2023-03-23 13:29:28,INFO,time taken,0 days 00:00:05.194268\r\n2023-03-23 13:29:28,INFO,waiting to get data,\r\n2023-03-23 13:29:28,INFO,time started:,2023-03-23 13:29:28.464997\r\n2023-03-23 13:29:28,INFO,start time for bulk :,2023-03-23 13:29:28.466010\r\n2023-03-23 13:29:28,INFO,time taken for process data to complete:,0 days 00:00:00.000086\r\n2023-03-23 13:29:28,INFO,data to ingest:,1\r\n2023-03-23 13:29:35,ERROR,Error 500,service not available\r\n2023-03-23 13:29:36,INFO,time taken,0 days 00:00:07.549076\r\n2023-04-17 07:47:51,INFO,waiting to get data,\r\n2023-04-17 07:47:55,ERROR,cosumer error,unable to consume messages\r\n2023-04-17 07:47:51,INFO,waiting to get data,\r\n'
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data))

# Use "time taken" to divide the rows into groups
df["group"] = (df["message"].shift() == "time taken").cumsum()

keep_info = {
    "data to ingest:": "date to ingest",
    "time started:": "time started",
    "time taken for process data to complete:": "time taken for process data",
    "Load target table completed with Append": "append time",
    "time taken": "time taken"}

# Keep only error rows or those with relevant info
df["error"] = error = df["level"] == "ERROR"
filtered = df[error | (df["message"].isin(keep_info))]

# Change the info labels
filtered["label"] = filtered["message"].replace(keep_info)

# Rearrange the error labels
filtered.loc[error, "label"] = "Error message"
filtered.loc[error, "value"] = filtered["message"] + " " + filtered["value"]

# Pivot by group, keeping date, value, and whether it is an error
reshaped = filtered.pivot(index="group", columns="label", values=["date", "error", "value"])

# Most of the information we need is from the 'value' column
result = reshaped["value"]

# Add the date from the time started rows
result["date"] = reshaped[("date", "time started")]

# 'type' is 'error' if there are any rows in the group where 'level' was 'ERROR'
result["type"] = reshaped["error"].any(axis=1).replace({True: "error", False: "info"})
```

Comment: File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3652, in get_loc
return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 147, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 176, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 7080, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 7088, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
ERROR!
KeyError: 'message'

Comment: Are you running the code as shown in my answer, or with a different `df`?

Comment: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/online-compiler/ 

i tried here with exact copy paste

Comment: It's because tabs are not preserved when copying from Stackoverflow to your compiler. I have put the data in comma-separated format instead. It should now work.

Comment: Thanks @Stuart, working your code. But how to pass my df to your code to work in this as expected

Comment: when i am passing my df only "info" data coming "error" one is not taking as expected

Comment: I used the data from your question - if the data in your real df is in a different format you will have to provide more details and try to isolate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
# ensuring its sorted by date
df['date_clean'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y-%m-%d %X')
df = df.sort_values('date', ascending=True)

# getting all start and end times
start_rows = df[df['message'] == 'time started:']
end_rows = df[df['message'] == 'time taken']

# data to return
data_to_return = []

# for every start row find the time taken row
for index, row in start_rows.iterrows():
    next_end_row_index = end_rows.loc[row['date'] < end_rows['date']].index[0]

    df_subset = df.loc[index:next_end_row_index]
    if 'ERROR' in df_subset.level.tolist():
        # identify the data from within the df_subset and append to df_to_return
        error_row = df_subset.loc[df_subset['level'] == 'ERROR', :]
        data_to_return.append({
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'message': error_row['message'].values[0],
            'date': error_row['date'].values[0]
        })

    else:
        # handle case for info
        pass

# Making DF to return and filling missing values with NA for error rows
pd.DataFrame(data_to_return).fillna('N/A')
```

Comment: is this complete solution or a suggestion to start? should i replace my whole code with this?

Comment: Thanks @amanbris, Am stuck with this since 4 days. if you can provide full solution, it will be a great help

Comment: Modified the solution to show how to populate the error case. I think you can use that to populate the info case as well.

Comment: @amanbris, i have updated my code in question with your feedback, am i doing anything wrong there?